# TextViews overlapping using a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I know I can use a `LinearLayout` to do this, but I have to use a `RelativeLayout` because I have another `RelativeLayout` that I need to anchor to the bottom of the overall layout, as sort of a "status" bar, and I want the title and text to be above the status bar, aligned to the top.  Using a `RelativeLayout` was the only way I could get the status bar to work.  The only problem is the title and text `TextViews` overlap each other and I need the text to be immediately below the title:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
         >       

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/status" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
              >
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/status" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                    />      
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/status"       
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/text" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"    
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LinearLayout as a children of RelativeLayout.

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">     
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/title" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML layouts are rendered in the order they are "read" in. So you would want to do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
         >       

           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/status"       
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/text" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"    
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
            />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/status" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
              >
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/status" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                    />      
            </RelativeLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I'd also wrap the two textViews in a linearLayout like someone else had mentioned. This will help you a lot.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from your text TextView. That'll solve your problem!